# Find $\lim_\limits{x\to 1^-}{\ln x\cdot \ln(1-x)}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

Find $\lim_\limits{x\to 1^-}{\ln x\cdot \ln(1-x)}$. I can't even start because I don't really know what $x\to 1^-$ means. If you know what it means it would really help me. I would as well if you helped me with finding the limit, hinted or thorough.

Comment: I did realize that tending to $1$ is problematic because of $ln(1-x)$, but is it possible to define a limit that way?

Comment: $x \to 1 - 0$ means $x$ is approaching $1$ from left. Like $0.9, 0.99, 0.999 \dots$. This ensures that $\ln{(1- x)}$ is well defined.

Comment: In such a situation, the rule of L'Hospital may help...

Comment: I shall try. But, first, I have to make it a quotient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\log(1-x)}{\frac1{\log x}}\stackrel{l'H}\rightarrow\frac{-\frac1{1-x}}{-\frac{\frac1x}{\log^2x}}=\frac{x\log^2 x}{1-x}\stackrel{l'H}\rightarrow\frac{\log^2x+2\log x}{-1}\xrightarrow[x\to1^-]{}0 $$

Comment: Thanks. Turned out I accidentally differentiated ${1\over \ln x}$ incorrectly .

Answer (score 1):

With *equivalents*, it's very short: set $x=1-u\enspace(u>0)$. Then $\ln x\ln(1-x)=\ln(1-u)\ln u$.

As $\ln(1-u)\sim_0 -u$, we have $\,\,\ln(1-u)\ln u\sim_0-u\ln u$, which tends to $0$ as $u$ tends to $0$.

Hence $$\lim_{x\to 1_-}\ln x\,\ln(1-x)=\lim_{u\to 0_+}\ln(1-u)\ln u=0.$$

Comment: is $\lim_{u \to 0+} \ln(1-u) \ln u$ not an indeterminate form $0.\infty?$

Comment: Yes, but taking the equivalent gives the answer.

Comment: what does taking the equivalent mean?

Comment: $f~_ag $ roughly means that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac fg=1$. Ver often, an equivalent is given by the first non-zero term of a Taylor expansion. Here, for instance, $\ln(1-u)=-u-\dfrac{u^2}2+\dots$, hence $\ln(1-u)\sim_0 u$. It's a powerful tool to replace complicated expressions by their meaningful (simpler) part.

Comment: ok i get it but i think it will be helpful to include an intermediate step $\ln(1- u) \ln u = u \ln u + \cdots$

Comment: I don't think so: it's a well known rule that equivalence is compatible with multiplication and division (but *not* with addition). You can take a look at this [Wikipedia notice](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Équivalent) (sorry it's in French, but the English version gives almost no details).

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x\uparrow1} \ln x \ln(1-x) = \lim_{x\uparrow1} \frac{\ln x}{x-1}\cdot\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1/(1-x)}.
$$

Apply L'Hopital's rule to both fractions and you've got it. (In the first one, the numerator and denominator both approach $0$; in the second, each approaches either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.)

Answer (score 1):

here is a way to avoid l'hospitals but will use the fact $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\ln n}{n} = 0$  let us do a change of variable $x = 1 - \dfrac{1}{n}.$ so  $$\ln x \ln (1- x) = \ln(1 - 1/n) \ln(1/n)=\ln n(-\ln(1- 1/n)=\ln n\int_{1-1/n}^1\dfrac{dt}{t}$$

we can use the bound $\dfrac{1}{n} \le \int_{1-1/n}^1\dfrac{dt}{t}  \le \dfrac{1}{n-1}$ to conclude $$ \dfrac{\ln n}{n} \le  \ln x \ln (1- x) \le \dfrac{\ln n}{n-1} $$

therefore the $$\lim_{x \to 1_-} \ln x \ln (1- x) = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

To prove that 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}\ln x\ln (1-x)=0,
\end{equation*}
it is possible to avoid, L'Hospital's rule, Taylor series and also to avoid
the limits
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}u\ln u=0,\ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty }\frac{\ln n}{n}=0.
\end{equation*}

It suffices to use the well-known inequality
\begin{equation*}
0\leq \ln x\ln (1-x)\leq \sqrt{x(1-x)},\ \ x\in (0,1).
\end{equation*}
and the squeeze theorem.

PS. An elegant proof of the well known inequality cited above maybe found here:

[with this inequality $\ln{x}\ln{(1-x)}<\sqrt{x(1-x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315955/with-this-inequality-lnx-ln1-x-sqrtx1-x).