# with this inequality $\ln{x}\ln{(1-x)}<\sqrt{x(1-x)}$

Tags: inequality

> If $0<x<1$, show that
>   $$\ln{x}\ln{(1-x)}<\sqrt{x(1-x)}$$

use derivative it's not easy, such 
$$
f(x)=(\ln{x}\ln{(1-x)})^2-x(1-x),
$$
$$
f'(x)=2x-1+\dfrac{2\ln{x}\ln^2{(1-x)}}{x}+\dfrac{2\ln^2{x}\ln{(1-x)}}{x-1}
$$
and we $f(x)=f(1-x)$,then we prove inequality hold in $x\in(0,1/2]$.
can you someone have brief solution?

Comment: Indirectly, you have to prove this. See if this helps. : $\cfrac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}}  > \cfrac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\ln(1-x)} $

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali no, that is NOT equivalent to the stated problem. You have the inequality switched around. When you divide by $\ln(1-x)$, you need to flip the inequality.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I made the typo out there. Thanks for pointing out, @avid19.

Comment: we known this:  $$\int_{0}^{1}\ln{x}\ln{(1-x)}dx=2-\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}<\dfrac{\pi}{8}=\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x(1-x)}dx$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $x\in (0,1)$ $$0<-\log(x)<\frac{1-x^2}{2x}.$$ This follows by [estimating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) the integral $$-\log(x)=\int_x^1\frac{dt}{t}$$ with a trapezoid. Also $\log(x)=2\log\sqrt{x}$ so $$0<-\log(x)<\frac{1-x}{\sqrt{x}}$$ on this interval and your inequality follows.

Comment: One beautiful solution!

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact a comment with a picture. The point is to obtain a formal symbolic proof of the inequality. Otherwise we could just offer

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use well known inequality,we have
$$\sqrt{ba}<\dfrac{b-a}{\ln{b}-\ln{a}},a>0,b>0$$
let $b=x,a=1$,then we have
$$\Longrightarrow \ln{x}>\dfrac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

$$\Longrightarrow -\ln{x}<\dfrac{1-x}{\sqrt{x}}\tag{1}$$
simaler we have 
$$-\ln{(1-x)}<\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x}}\tag{2}$$
$(1)\times(2)$ we have
$$\ln{x}\ln{(1-x)}<\sqrt{x(1-x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\ln x\ln (1-x)-\sqrt{x(1-x)},\ for\ 0<x\leq \frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
f^{\prime }(x) &=&\frac{\ln (1-x)}{x}-\frac{\ln x}{1-x}+\frac{x-\frac{1}{2}}{%
\sqrt{x(1-x)}} \\
&=&\frac{(1-x)\ln (1-x)}{x(1-x)}-\frac{x\ln x}{x(1-x)}+\frac{(x-\frac{1}{2})%
\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{x(1-x)} \\
f^{\prime }(x) &=&\frac{g(x)}{x(1-x)},\ where
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x) &=&(1-x)\ln (1-x)-x\ln (x)+(x-\frac{1}{2})\sqrt{x(1-x)} \\
g^{\prime }(x) &=&\sqrt{x\left( 1-x\right) }-\ln \left( 1-x\right) -\ln x+%
\frac{\left( -\frac{1}{4}\right) \left( 2x-1\right) ^{2}}{\sqrt{x\left(
1-x\right) }}-2 \\
g^{\prime \prime }(x) &=&\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{x}+3\frac{\left( \frac{1}{2}%
-x\right) }{\sqrt{x\left( 1-x\right) }}+\frac{\left( -\frac{1}{8}\right)
\left( 2x-1\right) ^{3}}{x\left( 1-x\right) \sqrt{x(1-x)}} \\
&=&h(x)\frac{\left( 2x-1\right) }{x\left( x-1\right) \sqrt{x(1-x)}},\ where\ 
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
h(x) &=&x-x^{2}-\sqrt{x-x^{2}}+\frac{1}{8} \\
h^{\prime }(x) &=&k(x)\frac{\left( \frac{1}{2}-x\right) }{\sqrt{x(1-x)}},\ \
where
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
k(x) &=&\left( 2\sqrt{x-x^{2}}-1\right)  \\
k^{\prime }(x) &=&\frac{2(\frac{1}{2}-x)}{\sqrt{x\left( 1-x\right) }}>0,\
for\ 0<x<\frac{1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I cannot understand what all these derivatives should say.